# LINQ to SQL Invalid Cast Issue

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, type-conversion

I'm getting an invalid cast exception but I'm not sure why, here is the list of my conversions:

```
SQL -> VB.NET
char(4) -> String
varchar(50) -> String
tinyint -> Integer
char(1) -> Char
bit -> boolean
smallint -> Integer
smallmoney -> Double
int -> Integer
datetime -> datetime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that `smallmoney` should go to `Decimal` instead... but why not just use a binary chop to try the first half, then the second etc to narrow down what's causing the problem?

If you could post the query involved, that would help too.

Comment: You are right, I came across this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx which really helped me out. Also, the following were correct conversions that I had messed up, smallint -> Int16 and tinyint -> byte.

Answer (score 0):

`smallmoney` maps to `Decimal`, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386947.aspx) (numeric mapping)